# Get Azure Retail Prices using Power BI (PowerQuery) Rest API

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

[image]

In the Above Picture we have **Items** and **NextPageLink**. Data is present inside **Items** and **NextPageLink** Contains links for next page data.

I am trying to automate a rest-API call with a Json response having several pages.
The idea would be to automatically call the **NextPageLink** until there is no **NextPageLink**.
I want to get data into single table.

Here is the link i am using to pull data : https://prices.azure.com/api/retail/prices

Here is last page link : https://prices.azure.com/api/retail/prices?$skip=408500

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create function **ReadSingle**

```
(offset) => 
let Source =Json.Document(Web.Contents(" https://prices.azure.com/api/retail/prices?$skip="& Number.ToText( offset )))[Items]
in Source
```

Use a loop to read in data.  You could repeat until done, but frankly my computer locked up, so Im doing pages 0-25, by 100's

```
let Source

= List.Generate(  
 ()  =>  [ Offset = 0, Data = ReadSingle(0) ],
 each [Offset] <= 2500, 
 each [ Data = ReadSingle( [Offset] ),
        Offset =  [Offset] + 100 ], 
 each [Data]
 ),

z=Table.FromColumns(Source),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(z, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Added Index", {"Index"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Index", "Attribute"}),
#"Expanded Value" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Value", {"currencyCode", "tierMinimumUnits", "retailPrice", "unitPrice",     "armRegionName", "location", "effectiveStartDate", "meterId", "meterName", "productId", "skuId", "productName", "skuName", "serviceName", "serviceId",     "serviceFamily", "unitOfMeasure", "type", "isPrimaryMeterRegion", "armSkuName"}, {"currencyCode", "tierMinimumUnits", "retailPrice", "unitPrice",     "armRegionName", "location", "effectiveStartDate", "meterId", "meterName", "productId", "skuId", "productName", "skuName", "serviceName", "serviceId",     "serviceFamily", "unitOfMeasure", "type", "isPrimaryMeterRegion", "armSkuName"})
in #"Expanded Value"
```

[image]

If you wanted to you could swap to repeat the loop until NextPageLink is a null. See my favorite reference on this [use List.Generate to make API Calls in Power Query M](https://gorilla.bi/power-query/list-generate-api-calls/)